# Match, case with logic?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

```
def searchEquipmentCategory(category: String) = Action {

    val equipment = Equipment.searchByCategory(category)
    equipment.size match {
        case 0 => NotFound(views.html.helpers.notfound("Equipment not found for category :" + category))
        case (_ > 0) => Ok(views.html.equipment.index(equipment, capitalize(category)))
    }

}
```

**Is it possible put logic in a match case statement?**

I've searched everywhere and can't find any documentation.  I just want to have if the case is 0 do one thing if the number is over 0.

Using the `_` default works fine in that situation, but what if I wanted to do 3 things?

- if number == 0
- if the number is between 1 and 10
- if the number is between 11 and 20

Maybe I'm trying to do too much with case.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
case i if i > 0 => Ok( ... )
```

So to distinguish between `0`, `1 to 10` and `11 to 20`:

```
case 0 =>
case i if i >=  1 && i <= 10 =>
case i if i >= 11 && i <= 20 =>
```

But then I guess an `if`-`else if`-`else` block is more readable.

Comment: Concerning the readability, you can omit the `( .. )` after the `if`, that makes it a bit easier to read.

Comment: @Mirko Hmmm, didn't know that! Nice!

Comment: Edited (removed parentheses)

Answer (score 6):

This is called guards:

```
case x if (x > 0) => OK ...
```